# Сортировка строк по количеству слов

Tags: c++, строки, векторы

Задача: Ввести с клавиатуры массив строк. Отсортировать его по возрастанию количества слов в каждой строке.

Получилось реализовать пока только чтение всех строк, дальше совсем не могу ничего придумать, как дальше считать слова и в дальнейшем менять строки местами?

Вот начало кода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void PrintVector(const vector<string>& v)
{
    for (string s : v)
        {
            cout << s << endl;
        }
}

int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n;
    cout << "Введите количество строк в массиве:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    vector <string> v;
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Введите сами строки:" << endl;
    while (i <= n )
        {
            string s;
            getline (cin, s);
            v.push_back(s);
            i++;
        }

    PrintVector(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как разделять строку на слова, было много вопросов и ответов. Выполняя то же самое, можете просто считать количество слов(тут нужно еще уточнить что есть слово для данной задачи).

```
 auto Pred = [](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
 {
    /*если разделитель пробел*/
    std::istringstream is1(s1), is2(s2);
    size_t k1{}, k2{}; //количество слов
    std::string t;
    while (is1 >> t) ++k1;
    while (is2 >> t) ++k2;
    return k1 < k2;
};
```

Дальше просто сортировать по данному предикату. Думаю тут не нужно менять местами строки, где количества слов одинаковы, поэтому использовать :

```
std::stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), Pred);
```